# Get updated data after modify a cell value in table by jQuery

Tags: blazor

I want to have the updated table in blazor webassembly application after modification cells by jquery.

**WeatherForecast.cs**

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF { get; set; }

  
}
```

**FetchData.razor**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class='odd'>@forecast.Id</td>
                <td class='odd'>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td class='odd'>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
            </tr>            
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since for modifying numbers in a table, I should use a Numpad I used a Jquery Numpad that will call the Numpad for all td in the table after clicking with odd class, and updating numbers works correctly.

```
 $('.odd').numpad();
```

but since jQuery made the update for cells, could I have updated data in blazor component?

----UPDATE ------

As I show in the image I made a table, and cell data update with Numpad.
[image]

it's https://github.com/kabachello/jQuery.NumPad/blob/master/demos/jquerymobile/index.htmljquery Numpad that I used in the project(it will appear after clicking on td and will update data).

My goal is to modify the numbers in table cells with a Numpad and have updated data on the blazor page after modification.

Comment: You've tagged this with Blazor, but you're asking a jQuery question?  Your question as asked is difficult to understand.  Why are you using jQuery? What is the behavior you're seeing? What is your intent?

Comment: If you change the value of an input through Javascript and you want to trigger the registered Blazor event on that input, you need to trigger the associated event, such as `onchange` or `oninput` as well as setting the value.   Something like `element.dispatchEvent(new Event("event"));`  Not recommended, but if needs must...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I realize that. I'm familiar with the boilerplate Blazor solution of weather forecasts too.  I was asking the question to get OP to be more clear.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I had assumed the OP would be doing something with Inputs to actually change the values.   I've just re-read the question and am now confused about how you would edit a div without using the ridiculous `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: Either create (or find) your own Numpad in Blazor logic (probably the best and safest) or make sure to execute a JS function getting the new value when "Done" button is pressed and sending it to Blazor by executing a `[JSInvokable]` c# function.